# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufe0f' in position 62: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, geolocation

I am trying to scrape geo locations based on the urls and after about 500 searches and extraction of geo location I am getting encoding error. I have included the encoding `utf-8` in the code and also followed the following command in the cmd.

```
chcp 65001
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

And yet I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 33, in <module>
    outputfile.write(newline)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufe0f' in position 62: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using Python 3.x updated version on anaconda of all the packages.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from twitter_location import get_location
from google_location import get_coordinates

# Open output file
outputfile = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

# Read input file
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding = "utf-8", errors='ignore') as csv:
    # Skip headers line
    next(csv)
    # Loop in lines
    for line in csv:
        # Extract userid
        print (line)
        permalink = line.split(',')[-1].strip()
        userid    = permalink.split('/')[3]
        # Get location as string if exists
        location = get_location(userid)
        if location is None:
            print ('user {} can not be reached or do not exposes any location.'.format(userid))
            continue
        else:
            # If location is ok, get coordinates
            coordinates = get_coordinates(location)
            print ('{}: {}'.format(userid, coordinates))

            # Copy current input line and add coordinates at the end
            newline = '{},{}\n'.format(line.strip(), coordinates)
            # Write in output file
            outputfile.write(newline)
```

I am looking for two things here

1. Help with the encoding error
2. I want to put back the input headers in the output + the new column header

My input files have following headers

```
username    date    retweets    favorites   text    geo mentions    hashtags    id  permalink
```

while writing the output I am able to get all the columns + the new geo coordinates column too. But I am not able to put back the headers in the output files.

Appreciate the help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already use an explicit `encoding` for the input file; just do the same for th output file in order to avoid the default CP-1252 to be used (`PYTHONIOENCODING` affects STDIN/STDOUT only, if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: As for the headers, I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to preserve the CSV's column headers, why don't you just write `outputfile.write(next(csv))` as the first instruction after opening the input file?

Comment: @lenz Thank you for the suggestion with encoding I did the same as you mentioned and seems to be working. Coming to my next query. I have couple of columns in input which I am able to get it in the output along with the new created geo location location columns. Here in the output I am not having headers and I want the headers names same as input + the new columns header. as `geoLocation`. how can I get that? when we use in program file name `write` function we can mention the headers. But here its little different and I am beginning with this kind.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. You need to clarify this with examples. Update the question or post a new one.

Comment: @lenz Edited the question with header names

Comment: I still don't understand the header issue. Headers aren't special, they're just the first line in a CSV file. Simply write a line with the adjusted headers to the output file before iterating over the contents.

Comment: @lenz yes I did try to write a statement like it is written for an output by '.write()' but that gave me some errors hence looking for some help..  I have like 100 csvs each with about 500k - 700k rows and the next operations are performed on pandas using header names. So I need to put back headers in outputs also.

Comment: That's a lot of vague information. Consider posting a new question, where you give enough detail of your problem. Show the input. Show the actual and the expected outcome. If you get errors, show them.